# Alternative to Properties Service for large amounts of data in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a GAS Search script that sends an API request and gets back results that I display in a Google Sheet. I have another Data Analysis script that does various data calculations based on the search results.

At the moment I use .getRange().getValues() in Data Analysis to get the values from the sheet. However, this is quite slow as it is a large multidimensional array.

Is there a way that I can store the initial search results in the Search script that I can then access in Data Analysis script?

I have tried using Google's Properties Service but the data is too large. Storing it in a sheet is also not an option as this is already what I am doing and it is very slow.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Cache service or external options like firestore or cloud storage or google drive

Comment: Reading the Cache service documentation, my data would be too large for it plus it is only temporary storage. I will look at firestore.

Comment: You have the option of leveraging alternative database/storage solutions such as Cloud Firestore or Cloud SQL, but these are services for which you'll have to pay.

Comment: @Dimu Firestore has a free tier

Comment: How large is the dataset? (number of rows). I faced the same problem and worked around it by creating a temp dummy sheet and programmatically running formulas on that sheet against the original dataset (DBGET, FILTER, etc). Still, there's no getting around the fact that GAS is quite slow for working with big data.

Comment: @TheMaster I know, but those [free quotas are very low](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas). You'd be surprised at how quickly one can exhaust them even for relatively small data-sets.

Comment: @AntonDementiev the maximum size of the dataset can be 5,000 - 6,000 rows but in practice 1,000 will probably be the highest number of rows. There are 11 columns.

Comment: @DimuDesigns I will look at Google Cloud, my app is very small at the moment and I just need a way of storing and retrieving one multidimensional array that doesn't take ages.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up copying and pasting values you shall use [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations), because many different calls to [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) is slow and inefficient. To run batch operations you will have to use [`getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) to create an array as big as your data table, and then use `getValues` on it to read them in just one operation. You will end up with a two-dimensional array filled with all your data. Finally, you can iterate this array to [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the elements that don't match your criteria.

If you want to paste your results over a sheet, you have to create a range as big as your results array and use [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) over it. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57853014) for a comparison of different copy-and-paste algorithms.

Please, tell me the details of your project if you want further help. Do not hesitate to ask me for more clarifications if you have any doubts.